# How to set imageurl and get image height and width dynamiclly in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, path

Here is the image which i want to set image url and find the height and width of this image dynamically.

```
<asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server"/>
```

//Assign the image path.

```
string Path= Server.MapPath("~/Images/testImage.jpg")
System.Drawing.Bitmap img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Path);
```

//Get the image height and width.

```
int height=0, width=0;
height = img.Height;
width = img.Width;
```

Comment: What is your question? What is your problem with this code?

Comment: What problem or error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use explicit conversion were we specifically ask the compiler to convert the value into another data type.

```
string Path= Server.MapPath("~/Images/testImage.jpg")
System.Drawing.Bitmap img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Path);

int height = (int)img.Height;
int width = (int)img.Width;
```